# How can I pass a braced-list / dynamic array into a function (c++)

Tags: c++

I have a function that accepts arrays of variable size, but it is still somewhat messy and I am having trouble condensing it into something that is easier to work with. I'm *not* asking to be spoonfed, but I am looking for some advice on how to potentially remedy this.

Here is how I have to setup variables to pass into the function, extremely tediously and redundantly:

```
DWORD xAAR[4] = { base, 0x5EC5E4, 0x5A8, 0x3C };
x = pGet(xAr, 5);
```

Here is how what I want to condense it to (bearing in mind that the amount of elements will differ for each usage):

```
x = pGet({ base, 0x5EC5E4, 0x5A8, 0x3C });
```

Below is the function itself, with the meat of it excluded for brevity.

```
DWORD pGet(DWORD p[], int sizeA)
{
    DWORD address;
    for (int i = 1; i < sizeA; i++)
    {
    }
    return NULL;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the following set of functions to make it easier to work with a whole host of containers.

```
template <typename Iterator>
DWORD pGet(Iterator begin, Iterator end)
{
   DWORD ret = 0;
   for (Iterator iter = begin ; iter != end; ++iter )
   {
      // Do something with the item.
   }
   return ret;
}

template <typename Container>
DWORD pGet(Container const& c)
{
   return pGet(std::begin(c), std::end(c));
}

DWORD pGet(std::initializer_list<DWORD> const& c)
{
   return pGet(std::begin(c), std::end(c));
}
```

Usage:

```
int main()
{
   DWORD base = 10;

   // Use pGet with an array.
   DWORD xAAR[4] = { base, 0x5EC5E4, 0x5A8, 0x3C };
   pGet(xAAR);
   pGet(xAAR, xAAR+2); // Work with a subset of the array.

   // Use pGet with an initializer_list.
   pGet({ base, 0x5EC5E4, 0x5A8, 0x3C});

   // Use pGet with a vector.
   std::vector<DWORD> v = { base, 0x5EC5E4, 0x5A8, 0x3C };
   pGet(v);
   pGet(v.begin(), v.begin()+2); // Work with a subset of the vector

   // Use pGet with a set.
   std::set<DWORD> s = { base, 0x5EC5E4, 0x5A8, 0x3C };
   pGet(s);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems like maybe you [varargs](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdarg/va_arg/) instead. This lets you call a function with a variable number of arguments, and the function can determine how many arguments there were.  This is how printf works, for example.

Another thought is to use initializer_lists, so you are no longer passing around raw arrays, but instead have it wrapped in a vector or something similar.

Comment: It is kind of a mess, but it is definitely more pleasing to call such a method.

Answer (score -1):

This looks simpler.

```
void print(int *a, int n)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        cout << a[i] << " ";
}
int main()
{
    print(new int[3] {1, 2, 3}, 3);
    cout << endl;
    print(new int[2] {2, 3}, 2);
    cout << endl;

    return 0;
}
```